# Why is Opera doing this with the dialog boxes?

Tags: kubuntu, text, opera, dialog

Opera is doing this:

[image]

I can't read what it says and it's really annoying. Chrome doesn't do that. I have to tilt my screen back to read it. Hopefully it's a quick and easy fix. I'm on Kubuntu 16.04 and Opera 41. If anyone would be able to help me, I'd appreciate it. I use both Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Du you use a theme? (In Ubuntu)

Comment: I am using the Simple Flow desktop theme.  I downloaded other ones too but when I tired to uninstall them, they're still there.